# Wildcard sub domains in IIS10

Tags: asp.net, iis, webserver, subdomain

I want to access the application **www.testsite.com** using different wildcard Sub-domain such as :

**abc.testsite.com 

xyz.testsite.com**

I have installed IIS Express 10 on windows 10 Machine and followed below steps:

1. Created an simple Asp.net MVC web application and published in local      folder
2. Added an website in local IIS as **www.testsite.com**
3. Mapped the website to the published folder.
4. Added binding as ***.testsite.com**
5. Edited host file with **127.0.0.1   www.testsite.com** and **127.0.0.1
     *.testsite.com**

Now I am able to access www.testsite.com but not using any other sub domains 
Am I missing anything ?

Comment: "127.0.0.1 *.testsite.com" is invalid. In hosts file or DNS you must explicitly state the sub domains.

Comment: But i need this as wildcard, I cannot predefined as per the requirement

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/135595/using-wildcards-in-names-in-windows-hosts-file You might need everything, but not all of them are achievable.

Comment: But I saw we can do wildcard entry on IIS 10 onwards https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-10/wildcard-host-header-support

Comment: IIS clearly allows your input, but hosts file not.

Comment: Got it thanks :) Any other work around to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add wildcard entry on IIS, but you have to specify the list of subdomains that you are going to map. Ultimately host file will not support any wildcard entry.